# LaunchScreen.storyboard is not showing

Tags: xcode, launch-screen

I started a single view app project on Xcode 12.5 and failed to locate the LaunchScreen.storyboard on the nevigation section. Where am I suppose to find it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have chosen wrong Life Cycle while creating the project: `SwiftUI App` instead of `UiKit App Delegate`, so there is no `LaunchScreen.storyboard` File.